# How do I attach a dynamic pdf to an email in Google App Script inside of a loop?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have created PDFs from a spreadsheet and would like to email them as an attachment. My issue is that I need to be able to send out the correct attachment to each email. I'm trying to do this by using the PDF name that is derived from a spreadsheet value indexing at 9.

So far I have created a variable that contains the PDF name (ID) and a variable that should then get the file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  data.forEach((row, i) => {
    var printed = row[10];
    if (printed != 1) {
      createPDF(row[2], row[3], row[0], row[4], row[1], row[5],row[7], row[6], row[8], docFile, TempFolder, pdfFolder);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i + 2, 11).setValue(1); 
      var ID = row[9];   
      var attachment = DriveApp.getFilesByName(ID);
      
      MailApp.sendEmail("fakeEmail@gmail.com","New Work Order","Please find the work order attached.\n\nThis is an automated message, do not respond",{
        attachments: [attachment.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]);}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the brackets

```js
        attachments: [attachment.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
```